# Reorder the columns based on another DataFrame without manually type the column names

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two DataFrames `df1` and `df2` which contain both the same columns but in a different order. Is there an efficient way to reorder the columns of `df2` based on the order of the columns of `df1` without manually specifying the column names?

This would be a simple example:

```
df1
    Date        ID1 ID2 ID3 ID4 ID5
0   2021-01-01  0   1   0   1   0
1   2021-01-02  0   0   1   0   0
2   2021-01-03  1   0   1   1   0

df2
    Date        ID4 ID2 ID1 ID3 ID5
0   2021-01-01  1   1   0   0   0
1   2021-01-02  0   0   0   1   0
2   2021-01-03  1   0   1   1   0
```

For reproducibility:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Date':['2021-01-01', '2021-01-02', '2021-01-03'],
    'ID1':[0,0,1], 
    'ID2':[1,0,0],
    'ID3':[0,1,1], 
    'ID4':[1,0,1], 
    'ID5':[0,0,0]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Date':['2021-01-01', '2021-01-02', '2021-01-03'],
    'ID4':[1,0,1],
    'ID2':[1,0,0],
    'ID1':[0,0,1], 
    'ID3':[0,1,1],     
    'ID5':[0,0,0]})
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reorder the columns by passing a column list -

In your case, to use the columns on the first dataframe on the second `df2[df1.columns]`